# Duplicate values while batching a large Django QuerySet

Tags: python, django, list-comprehension, django-queryset

I'm generating batches of phone numbers of clients. I've got a large (25m+) table of Subscriber objects that I'm searching through to find matching records, then looking up the numbers for each one through Django's ForeignKey relationship (the Subscriber objects have a ForeignKey to the Customer objects, which then have a CharField that contains the number). For large QuerySets, I'm getting duplicate numbers in the batches. On a list of about 110k subscribers, I get about 5k duplicates.

I'm generating the initial QuerySet with a straighforward filter:

```
subscribers = Subscribers.objects.filter(foo='bar')
```

This is how I then generate the batches:

```
batches = [
    [s.customer.number for s in subscribers[x:x + batch_size]]
    for x in xrange(0, subscriber_count, batch_size)
]
```

When I test this method in the shell, it works just fine; only in production does it ever fail. It also works great for smaller QuerySets in production. Only QuerySets about 50k+ seem to be having problems. Also, when I try just creating a list of the Subscriber objects from the QuerySet, everything works great:

```
print list(subscribers)
```

works correctly, even in production. So it seems like the

```
s.customer.number
```

is somehow doing the lookup wrong occasionally, but only for large QuerySets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that in `batches` you need only the customer number. Then, **take from queryset only relevant data**:

```
cnumbers =    ( Subscribers
                .objects
                .filter(foo='bar')
                .values_list('customer__number', flat=True)
                .distinct()
               )
```

To make chunks:

```
batches = [
           [cnumbers[x:x+batch_size] 
           for x in xrange(0, len(cnumbers), batch_size)]
          ]
```

The cause of duplicate value in your approach can be due to data, perhaps do you have two subscribers referencing same customer.

Comment: This worked. I'm curious as to why Django couldn't handle the normal lookup, but as long as it's working.

Also, I didn't need the .distinct() call. It worked just fine without that.